# Play a sound clip while recording video using UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController that is recording video and i want to play a 3 second sound clip while the video is recording.

Right now when the audio starts, the video stops recording. How can I keep the video recording while i play this sound?

Thanks